# Why does Anaconda Navigator keeps crashing on Start Up (Mac)?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, startup

I'm new to programming and started a couple of month ago learning Python.
I installed Anaconda and work on Spyder. That was working just fine.

But since a couple of weeks, Anaconda isn't starting anymore.

I found a solution online to reset the config:

```
anaconda navigator --reset
```

that work just fine but just for 24 hours or so. The next day Anaconda refuse to start again, so I'm confused.

Is it a package (psutil) that I would have installed that got my config unstable and how could I fix that plz ?
Here is the message a get on start-up:

```
Navigator Start Up Error
psutil.AccessDenied (pid=533)

>Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/yannickleroux/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 293, in wrapper
return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/yannickleroux/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 356, in cmdline
return cext.proc_cmdline(self.pid)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/yannickleroux/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/exceptions.py", line 75, in exception_handler
return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/yannickleroux/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/start.py", line 108, in start_app
if misc.load_pid() is None: # A stale lock might be around
File "/Users/yannickleroux/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/misc.py", line 384, in load_pid
cmds = process.cmdline()
File "/Users/yannickleroux/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 701, in cmdline
return self._proc.cmdline()
File "/Users/yannickleroux/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 306, in wrapper
raise AccessDenied(self.pid, self._name)
psutil.AccessDenied: psutil.AccessDenied (pid=533)
```

Comment: Did you install any packages using `sudo`?

Comment: Yes a few... virtualenv setuptools and certainly other I dont't remember... I am a newbie and dont really get that sudo command ... and the consequences of using it during an install

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do is to remove the `/Users/yannickleroux/anaconda/` folder using `sudo` and reinstall Anaconda. You could also try to change the ownership of that folder using `chown`, you can look around for instructions. You should not use sudo to install packages for Anaconda, use `conda` only. Also, you should not use `virtualenv`, use conda environments.

Comment: Thank you, yes I have a big mess to clean that I created when I just started and followed tutorials here ans there without knowing too much what I was doing

Answer (score 1):

Please **update** anaconda navigator:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
```